# PowerApps exist function issue?

Tags: powerapps

**Power `Exist()` Function issue**
Need close tab on button click but.

It's working but the behaviour of the `exist()` function does not work as expected. `exist()` launches another Dynamic 365 Tab, but I need to close the App Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Powerapps does not have a Exist() function. Maybe you wanted to say Exit():
[Exit() powerapps function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-exit)